# ZF2 Only make a form element required based on another element?

Tags: validation, zend-framework2, zend-form2

So I have a list of elements in my form, one of which is a select box with a simple yes/no option. When the field is 'no' I want to make the next input field required.

At the moment my input filter looks like:

```
return [
    [
        'name' => 'condition',
        'required' => true,
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'additional',
        'required' => false,
        'validators' => [
            [
                'name' => 'callback',
                'options' => [
                    'callback' => function($value, $context) {
                        //If condition is "NO", mark required
                        if($context['condition'] === '0' && strlen($value) === 0) {
                            return false;
                        }
                        return true;
                    },
                    'messages' => [
                        'callbackValue' => 'Additional details are required',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'string_length',
                'options' => [
                    'max' => 255,
                    'messages' => [
                        'stringLengthTooLong' => 'The input must be less than or equal to %max% characters long',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

What I am finding is because I have `'required' => false,` for the `additional` field, none of the `validators` run.

How do I make `additional` required ONLY when `condition` is 'no' (value '0')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to retrieve the elements from within the `getInputFilterSpecification` function. As such, it is possible to mark an element as `required` or not based on the value of another element in the same form or fieldset:

```
'required' => $this->get('condition')->getValue() === '0',
```

With this, I can also get rid of the massive `callback` validator too.

```
return [
    [
        'name' => 'condition',
        'required' => true,
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'additional',
        'required' => $this->get('condition')->getValue() === '0',
        'validators' => [
            [
                'name' => 'string_length',
                'options' => [
                    'max' => 255,
                    'messages' => [
                        'stringLengthTooLong' => 'The input must be less than or equal to %max% characters long',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```